# In image_link setting, How can I change "content" to the specific node

Tags: entities

[The example in API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7) show that 'image_link' => 'content', How can I change "content" to the specific node. This is my code in basic page:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_pg_image');
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_pg_image', $image[0], array(
  'type' => 'image',
  'settings' => array(
  'image_style' => 'thumbnail',   
  'image_link' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
),
));
print render($output);
```

I would like to change 'image_link' => 'xxxxxxxxx' to "node/30?ptype=20"; How to do this

Answer (score 1):

keep

```
'image_link' => 'content',
```

and after your code, before print:

```
$output['#path']['path'] = "node/30?ptype=20";
```